# What's the created Date-time for Table row in Oracle?

Tags: database, oracle, timestamp

Yesterday my friend -BI Specialist - explained me an oracle problem :
there's an oracle database that contain huge amount of data but they don't make column for each table that store Created datetime for each row.
So in this case **How can he get Created datetime (timestamp) for each row ?**

Comment: do you mean in an existing database with huge amounts of existing data?  is any kind of Auditing enabled?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Every row has its own System Change Number (SCN). This is identifying precisely a moment in the database.

First find out the SCN and based on it use SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP to get the time-stamp:

```
SELECT 
  SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn),
  MyTable.*
FROM 
  MyTable
```

Comment: It's also worth noting that `SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP()` may not be available for older data (however, `ORA_ROWSCN` is always available).

Comment: Also note that by default the `ora_rowscn` is recorded at the block level (NOROWDEPENDENCIES is the default CREATE TABLE option). See for example http://asktom.oracle.com/pls/apex/f?p=100:11:0::NO::P11_QUESTION_ID:517105100346104196

Comment: Also this pseudo-column would only store the "last updated time", not the "creation time"

Comment: You may get an error: `supplied scn was beyond the bounds of a valid scn`. Perhaps it was caused by too much data or old records which don't have the scn? Anyhow, try running it on one a single row - the newest one.

Comment: This answer worked for me.  However, I suggest changing to: `SELECT SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn), MyTable.* FROM MyTable` so we know which rows the timestamps belong to.

Comment: You are wrong, SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn) returns the last modified date of a record, not the insert-time. So for every update you make on that record, the SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP(ora_rowscn) will return a different timestamp refered to the timestamp over the record was affected by the last change