# Oracle record (row) metadata include timestamp

Tags: sql, oracle, metadata, record

Does an Oracle database log a timestamp for each record (row) written to a table?
If so is there an SQL command to read this timestamp?

I am trying to find out how long it is taking to perform a write to the database.  The record of data contains a time stamp of when the test data was ready to write to the database.  The difference of this time would tell me how long the write is taking.  Note I am not looking for mS differences I am looking at minute differences.

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the created Date-time for Table row in Oracle?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6571575/whats-the-created-date-time-for-table-row-in-oracle)

Answer (score 3):

Though there is not exactly a timestamp for each row, you can use something similar called SCN, you can obtain that in the pseudocolumn [ORA_ROWSCN](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/pseudocolumns007.htm#BABFAFIC)
and afterwards transform it to a timestamp by using [SCN_TO_TIMESTAMP](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions142.htm)

Also as @SanderstheSoftwarer states in the comments: "the table can be built with ROWDEPENDENCIES option and if so, scn would be tracked for every row".

Comment: As stated by in the link, by default, ORA_ROWSCN is tracked by block not row.

Comment: @Shannon you are correct, and as you can read in my answer i'm not pretending to give an answer targeted at the row level but a similar solution with a close enough usefulness given that the OP intends for a minute level difference not ms

Comment: @Shannon, it depends. Table can be built with ROWDEPENDENCIES option and if so, scn would be tracked for every row. Internally it adds a hidden column into the table and automatically updates it every time on row writing.